# How many ways are there of tying a tie?

Tags: combinatorics, knot-theory

I am sorry if this is useless.

I have read in a newspaper that mathematicians have found the number of ways a tie can be tied. How could such a problem be solved?

I'm asking out of curiosity.

Comment: Well I tie mine with a square knot, so there is $1$ way.

Comment: A good answer to this question should not be a number, but a sequence, where the infinitely many ways to tie a tie are grouped together in some way according to their complexity.

Answer (score 3):

You can read the solution to your question here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_85_Ways_to_Tie_a_Tie. [solution of 1999, seems outdated]

Comment: Now see this number http://www.popsci.com/article/science/there-are-177147-ways-tie-tie. I was talking about this figure and this figure really surprised me.

Comment: I't would be very interesting if pysical limitations like length of the tie or thickness of the fabric where taken into consideration.